# How can I determine the default branch for a github repo from the github web UI?

Tags: github

I want to determine which branch in a repo is the default branch, but I'd like to not have to resort to http requests to do that.  Is there someplace in the GitHub web UI that shows the default branch for a repo?

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a support request to github.com asking that they display the name of the default branch in the Web UI, and got a very quick response:

"Thanks for the suggestion. We'll keep this in mind. The default branch is always the branch shown on the main repository page, but I can understand that this isn't necessarily obvious."